# How to turn an android app to a ROS node

Tags: ros, android-teleop, mobile, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do I write a android app like the android ROS teleop app? Do I have to use rosjava? Is there any open sourced project or not-outdated tutorials? What is the current state-of-art way to make a mobile app to a node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272531/how-to-turn-an-android-app-to-a-ros-node/) by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-10-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@rozoalex the "most standard" way of running ROS on Android is using Rosjava and RosAndroid.
Take a look here: http://wiki.ros.org/android (kinetic tab) and here: http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava. The documentation is a bit basic but it can get you going. In short, Rosjava will provide you the infrastructure you need to execute code as ROS nodes, send messages, etc. All of that can be triggered within an Android activity.

Depending on what you want to do, you may want to modify existing apps (like teleop), which are actually open source. Take a look at https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps, you don't need to start from scratch. Perhaps some of the existing components will help you out in your application.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rozoalex](https://answers.ros.org/users/31065/rozoalex/) on 2017-10-10**:
Thanks! Is there some recommended resource for doing iOS node? I just found these : https://github.com/tomas789/iOSmsg and https://github.com/tomas789/iOSmsg_client

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2017-10-10**:
Sorry, I can't help you with that one. There is no "official" or "close to official" implementation of ROS that can run on iOs that I'm aware of. Those links seem to provide partial implementation to pass messages; perhaps that's enough for your application.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, we developed an Android application based on the current architectural pattern Model View ViewModel. It is open source and can be found here:

https://github.com/ROS-Mobile/ROS-Mobile-Android

or directly at the android app store

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schneewittchen.rosandroid

---

Originally posted by [NRottmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/33772/nrottmann/) with karma: 36 on 2020-07-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1